# angular-fullstack throwing uncaught sybtax error < in the rowser

Tags: gruntjs, angular-fullstack

I am using yeoman angular-fullstack generator for my app and its working fine in grunt serve but throwing Uncaught syntax errors '<' in grunt serve:dist.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the rep to comment but it's likely being caused when your application tries to load something and throws a 404 which causes the 404 route to be hit which renders the 404 error page causing the first character to be `'<html...'.`

Check the network requests and responses for the offending request.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question referencing this one if it will help provide context.

Comment: As I noted in my answer I don't have the rep to leave a comment. As far as the answer to his question goes. With the information given this is as close as you can get, which is to say conjecture.